# SqlServer Short-Circuit Optimization in Queries

Tags: sql, sql-server

Does SQL Server use short-circuits in query logic, similar to most programming languages?  I have a procedure with many possible filters that default to '%' and then are used in a `aField LIKE @filter` clause.  If the user uses the default, I'd ideally like to short-circuit that particular filter, like  `(@filter = '%' OR aField LIKE @filter)`

If I read other short-circuit questions and answers correctly, the query processor can choose to process in any order or both.  (To preempt, for maintenance/clarity reasons, I don't want to write dynamic SQL).

Is there a way to force a short-circuit?

Comment: Short answer - no. For more in-depth discussion see [updated kitchen sink](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-updated-kitchen-sink-example) and [dynamic search conditions](https://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html)

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to force a short-circuit?

Yes.  For the special case of expressions like `(@filter = '%' OR aField LIKE @filter)` you can enable them to be simplified *before* the query plan is optimized with OPTION RECOMPILE [query hint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-query?view=sql-server-ver15).

Without OPTION RECOMPILE SQL Server will create a query plan that will be reused for any value of `@filter`, which requires the expression to be evaluated to filter rows.

Comment: That's not technically a short-circuit, it's contradiction detection (with parameter embedding). If contradiction detection doesn't work (such as if a non-determinstic function was present) then both conditions will remain in the query